# What is the best setup of mod_mono with more virtual hosts?

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, mono

I have VPS on debian, where I want to host at least 20 virtual hosts running mono application. On PHP I was using mpm_itk to run each vhost under its own user (I thing it is good for security and space usage control).

Is here possibility to run mono applications for each vhost under its own system user? I know it is possible to run more mono servers, but it is resource-expensive...

Answer (score 0):

Taken from mono [mod_mono documentation](http://www.mono-project.com/Mod_mono):

> Mod_mono is an Apache module that is hosted inside Apache. Depending on your configuration the Apache box could be one or a dozen of separate processes, all of these process will send their ASP.NET requests to the mod-mono-server process. The mod-mono-server process in turn can host multiple independent applications. It does this by using Application Domains to isolate the applications from each other, while using a single Mono virtual machine.